# There is Array.push function in solidity how it is return length of the array?

Tags: solidity

pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.6.0;

contract ZombieFactory {

```
event NewZombie(uint zombieId, string name, uint dna);

uint dnaDigits = 16;
uint dnaModulus = 10 ** dnaDigits;

struct Zombie {
    string name;
    uint dna;
}

Zombie[] public zombies;

function _createZombie(string memory _name, uint _dna) private {
    uint id = zombies.push(Zombie(_name, _dna)) - 1; //**here how it is return length of array**
    emit NewZombie(id, _name, _dna);
}

function _generateRandomDna(string memory _str) private view returns (uint) {
    uint rand = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_str)));
    return rand % dnaModulus;
}

function createRandomZombie(string memory _name) public {
    uint randDna = _generateRandomDna(_name);
    _createZombie(_name, randDna);
}
```

}

***I want to know how it is working i tired to searched in google but i cant get exact results try to explain how it returning length of array and basically it just add the element ...***

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before solidity v0.6.
Arrays have a member "push" define as :
Dynamic storage arrays and bytes (not string) have a member function called push that you can use to append an element at the end of the array. The element will be zero-initialised. The function returns the new length.
It's changed after v0.6.
Reference https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/060-breaking-changes.html